# pentaho data integration - how to automatically run a transformation/job on mac

Tags: macos, cron, pdi

I am using **PDI version 7.1** on Mac. the transformation and job are stored in Documents. I know that I can create a job and schedule a job on **START** to run the transformation on a specified time, but for this method, I have to run the job, otherwise, it cannot run automatically. is there another method to automatically run the job or transformation everyday on Mac? I tried `crontab -e` on mac terminal, but it says I don't have the permission to access the file, how can I solve it?

Comment: What is the command you are trying to run in crontab? Have you tried to run the same command manually, and does that work?

Comment: i run 59 11 * * * /Applications/data-integration/kitchen.sh

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, we use the Task Scheduler. Through it I choose how my task will be scheduled, hourly, daily... You must call the file `Kitchen.bat` to start the job on pdi. On MAC OS is `Kitchen.sh`.

I find this [link](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/schedule-automator-tasks-mac-os-x-39132.html), maybe help you.

Comment: I am not familiar with terminal, can you post your command so I can try work out on PC

Comment: I gave the other answer because I needed to use some formatting that was not possible in comments. See if it helps! :>

Answer (score 0):

As I said, I use the Task Scheduler on **Windows** for this. In the Task created I add a **Start a Program** action by calling `cmd.exe`, passing the command line that runs the `Kitchen.bat` file with my job file.

[My example in image on Windows.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37UEc.jpg)

Program/Script:
`C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe`

Arguments: 
`/C ""C:\Pentaho\data-integration\Kitchen.bat" /file "C:\Jobs\job.kjb""`